# Getting a sphere to roll down a .FBX object Unity3D/C#

Tags: c#, physics, unity

I'm working on a little ramp and ball game in Unity, I modeled the ramp outside Unity and exported it to a .FBX file, then I imported the ramp in to Unity. I set up the ball and ramp, both have Rigidbodies, Ramp is set to isKinematic = true, yet when I play the game the ball just falls right through the ramp and hits the floor below it fine. So it's something wrong with the ramp.

Am I doing something wrong? Are .FBX files unable to apply physics?

Thanks,

Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can apply physics to a fbx derived mesh. Make sure the mesh has a MeshCollider and the ball has a SphereCollider.

Make sure you have the Generate Colliders option checked:

[image: FBXImporter Options]

Also make sure that the Mesh for the ramp is set in the MeshCollider on your GameObject:

[image: MeshCollider]

Comment: Yup, the mesh has a MeshCollider and the ball has a SphereCollider

Comment: Make sure the ball's SphereCollider is not intersecting the ramp's Collider or it will just fall through it. Can you post a screen snap of the scene?

Comment: It's not, for testing I have the ball fall on a surface that does work (the red pillar) roll off that on to the ramp, but it just falls through the ramp and hits the floor. [picture](http://tinypic.com/r/dc6d52/5)

Comment: Thank you SO much, that did turn out to be the problem. Marked correct.

Comment: Updated my answer, check these and send results..

Comment: Yep, they worked out. Although it appears that once I check that box I no longer need a "mesh collider" or the rigidbody to get the ramp to work.

Comment: Ok good, I'm guessing that Unity manages the mesh collider if you add the rigidbody component. I had the same issue with bodies falling through on startup if there was any intersection happening. Even if the objects were close to touching, they would fall through so you may have to start your ball away from the ramps like you mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, everything works fine now. I don't need the mesh collider or rigidbody for the ramp, it works fine with just the box checked :)

Comment: This is a fine solution, but consider to use a rotated box collider on top of your mesh. Mesh colliders are'nt as robust to physics as box colliders and even more important box colliders are perform much better. If you need use a lot of meshcolliders your game performace will definitly drop.

Comment: @jonas I totally agree. This answer was tailored to the issue around supporting physics in .fbx files and I should have mentioned your concerns.